# Rotate UITableViewCell inside a rotated UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, rotation

Rather than implementing a clunky, potentially bug-ridden custom table, I went with the much simpler rotate table option. The problem comes in when I decide that, rather than initializing rotated contents, I want to rotate the cell itself and cut down on the amount of code in complex cells.

The following lines are immediately after cell configuration.

This causes every cell to rotate 90° on load, regardless of orientation:

```
cell.transform =
      (CGAffineTransform)CGAffineTransformRotate(cell.transform, (M_PI / 2.0));

cellRotated = YES;
```

And this option only rotates the first cell once, but preserves the rotation:

```
if (!cellRotated) {
    cell.transform =
      (CGAffineTransform)CGAffineTransformRotate(cell.transform, (M_PI / 2.0));

    cellRotated = YES;
}
```

Can cell orientation be tracked with an existing function (or set thereof)?

I can't find anything about this with Google. There are related questions, but mostly about tables and Portrait/Landscape UI orientations, so the counter-rotation implementation is quite a bit different.

---

**EDIT**

If I move `cellRotated = YES` to `viewDidAppear:` every cell except one gets rotated. (And then cell reuse makes it so that, in this case, every sixth cell is left alone.)
1-5 is good, 6 is bad, 7-11 is good, 12 is bad, etc (and then it changes in a perfectly logical but entirely unwanted pattern when I hit the end of the table)

Halfway there or a step back, I don't know, but that's what I have now.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this? I ask because there might be other ways to achieve the effect.

Comment: @mackross As I said, I want to have relatively simple code to allow for a horizontally scrolling table. Rotate the table, then counter-rotate the cells. Two pieces that work almost everywhere, as opposed to half a dozen that work in very specific situations. Reusable code is good. // Yes, there are other ways, but cell rotation is the fastest and easiest to plug into another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If rotation is the only transform you do then why don't you just do this,

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0);
```

and then,

```
if ( !CGAffineTransformIsIdentity (cell.transform) ) {
    // Rotated.
}
```

Comment: Yes, that. Thanks, Deepak. // Edit: I only need the first line. Even better. // Now to make the table behave. It keeps increasing width for some reason.

Comment: Increasing? You can try swapping `M_PI/2.0` with `M_PI_2` to be precise. And `frame` property is undefined if transform isn't identity.

Comment: Right, right. I misread the `if`. (The width increase was there before I tried to rotate cells. I don't think they're related.)

Comment: Ah! my mistake. There should've been a `!` in there. Edited.

Comment: So that's all working, but I'm still lost on the table thing. New question, I guess.

Comment: Scratch that. I had them set to autoresize for some reason. Stupid mistake.